# Dynamic Proxying IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

I'm trying to create a dynamic proxy to a list of objects of a specific class.
For example:

```
var proxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(typeof (IEnumerable<string>),
                                                        interceptor);
```

But I get the following exception:

> Cannot resolve method System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.__Canon] GetEnumerator() because the declaring type of the method handle System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] is generic. Explicitly provide the declaring type to GetMethodFromHandle.

I'm trying to proxy an IEnumerable<> in order to cache calls to generate the list itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to create some Cache-class that implements IEnumerable and consumes some source of items?

Comment: It might be, but for now I am interested if this is possible.

Comment: The System.__Canon confuses me, but either it seems that the castle is doing bad reflection against a generic type. Have you tried proxying some random generic interface you yourself specify?

Comment: You can create a proxy of `IEnumerable<string>`, that's not the problem. The most likely issue is some code in your interceptor (or elsewhere), but it's most likely impossible to diagnose unless you show it to us.

Comment: @flq The `__Canon` [is normal](http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,1fa8a82b-a6d6-4fbb-8cca-5e352ff3c9e9.aspx) to see during runtime.